# Call a KeyDown Event

Tags: javascript, call, keydown

All I need is to be able to click a button and have it do the KeyDown event for Enter, I've tired doing KeyDownCheck(13); and similar things, and I can get into the KeyDown event, but I can't get it to recognize that I want Enter, and it doesn't go to any specific key.

All Enter does is call another function, but when I try to call the function from a button it seems to call a different function which puts me back. Ironically, I had the same problem in the Enter event, but I fixed it with a return false; statement and I don't know how to do that for a button, so I was just going to call the KeyDown.

Is there a specific way to put this in? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail, maybe show some of your code? What's the effect you want to achieve with this simulated event? (I'm asking because there's usually a better, more direct way.)

Comment: I edited in more details, sry that took so long.

Comment: Bump? Maybe? Does that work on this site?

Answer (score 0):

Notice, that key events are heavily browser specific. It is no fun at all really especially with none alphanumeric keys like 'enter'.
See [here](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) for a full run-down on all the issues.
See [here](http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html) for a test script, that helps you to determine the results your browser gives you.

Comment: I've already gone through a month of making the KeyDown work the same in all the different browsers and OSs. I think, the KeyDown should work fine. I just need to call it somehow.

Comment: Best show some code of what you are doing. Your description is very confusing. Also your proposed solution to your problem seems a bit complicated. I don't see why another function is called in the click event of your button. Do you mean afterwards the button does something else too? In that case try to call both stopPropagation and preventDefault on the event after you handled it.

I don't believe there is a cross-browser way to initiate keyboard events programatically using javascript.